# Fire action when two promises are complete

Tags: scala, promise

I want to have some action completed ONCE, when two promises are success. So I created such a piece of code:

```
val promiseForPersistence = Promise[Unit]()
val promiseForReplication = Promise[Unit]()

promiseForPersistence.future.onComplete {
  case scala.util.Success(_) => {
    if (promiseForReplication.isCompleted) {
      println(s"Acking from persistence promise (replication one already completed)" )
    }
  }
  case _ =>
}

promiseForReplication.future.onComplete {
  case scala.util.Success(_) => {
    if (promiseForPersistence.isCompleted) {
      println(s"Acking from replication promise (persistence one already completed)" )
    }
  }
  case _ =>
}

promiseForPersistence.success()
promiseForReplication.success()
```

The problem is, both log messages are printed. I want the action to be fired only once. Why it is fired twice, and how can I have it fire only once?

Comment: Another [Coursera "Reactive Programming"](https://class.coursera.org/reactive-001) student I see! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `isCompleted` method on `Future` for this purpose. You should combine 2 futures in a single future using `flatMap` like this:

```
for {
  _ <- promiseForPersistence.future
  _ <- promiseForReplication.future
} println("Both are completed" )
```

Callback in `onComplete` could be evaluated after both `Promise`s are completed. So you'll get `isCompleted == true` in both callbacks and 2 `println` messages.

Valid way is to add callback in callback:

```
promiseForPersistence.future.onSuccess { _ =>
  promiseForReplication.future.onSuccess { _ =>
    println(s"Acking from replication promise (persistence one already completed)" )
  }
}
```

You'll get exactly the same behavior with `flatMap` (`for-comprehension`), but with less verbose syntax.